# SelectionSort implemented with Generic Method - Wrong Results

Tags: java, sorting, generics

I'm working through Deitel & Deitel's "Java - How To Program" and I'm stumped on why this implementation I came up with of a generic selection sort method is not working. I'm sure I must be missing some small detail, but after researching the API and a few resources on Generics, I'm coming up cold. While the program runs and performs some kind of sort, it definitely does NOT come out sorted in numerical order! I can't tell if I'm misunderstanding Generics, or just the selection sort algorithm. Any help would be appreciated!

The output I receive on running the selection sort on the intArray is: 
0, 1, -23, 7, 54

The output for the floatArray after the sort is: 
-1.1, -10.3, 0.4, 4.5

***UPDATE*** I just tried this without using negative values and it sorts fine, what is that about???

Here is the complete Sorter class that performs the selection sort:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sorter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] intArray = {1, 7, -23, 54, 0};
        Float[] floatArray = {0.4f, -10.3f, 4.5f, -1.1f};

        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
        ArrayList<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(floatArray));

        System.out.printf("Lists before selectionSort: %n%s%n%s%n%n",
            intList, floatList);

        selectionSort(intList);
        selectionSort(floatList);

        System.out.printf("Lists after selectionSort: %n%s%n%s%n%n",
            intList, floatList);
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void selectionSort(ArrayList<T> list) {
        // helps determine whether or not a swap will occur
        boolean needsSorting = false;
        // keeps track of the index of the smallest value
        int smallest = 0;

        // outer for walks the portion of the list that will be swapped
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            // inner for searches for a smaller value than the front of list
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                // if the inner value is less than the outer value
                if (list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(i)) < 0) {
                    // store the index of the smaller value
                    smallest = j;
                    // set the boolean flag to true so the sort will happen
                    needsSorting = true;
                }
            }

            // if the list needs sorting
            if (needsSorting) {
                // get the value of the outer loop, store in generic variable
                T temp = list.get(i);
                // replace value of outer loop with value at the smallest index
                list.set(i, list.get(smallest));
                // replace value at what was smallest index with the value that
                // was at the index of the outer loop
                list.set(smallest, temp);

                needsSorting = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be occurring at this line,

```
if (list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(i)) < 0)
```

Instead of `list.get(i)`, it should be `list.get(smallest)`

Also, you're not updating smallest, when you should be doing so in each iteration of the outer for loop. Add this line of code right after `for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++)`

```
smallest = i;
```

Comment: Thanks, I caught that once you pointed out where the problem was. You da man!

Comment: Check out my edit, I think that fix should work because you're supposed to update the smallest variable to start at the beginning of the unsorted list as the sorted list grows in length by 1 after each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

DaneBrick set me in the right direction. I needed to set the smallest variable to be equal to i, the counter for the outer loop, for each iteration of the outer loop. Here is the corrected portion of the code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        // inner for searches for a smaller value than the front of list
        //*** NEW PORTION, DIDN'T HAVE THIS BEFORE ***//
        smallest = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            // if the inner value is less than the outer value
            if (list.get(j).compareTo(list.get(smallest)) < 0) {
                // store the index of the smaller value
                smallest = j;
                // set the boolean flag to true so the sort will happen
                needsSorting = true;
            }
        }
```